# Proof of no identity element in a multiplication semi group

Tags: group-theory, semigroups

I have a question from my workbook:

> Let $\mathrm{E}$ denote the set of even integers. This forms a semi-group under multiplication. Show that there is no identity in this semi-group.

Now this is obvious, as $1 \not\subset \mathrm{E}$

How do I prove this problem without using anything but the given multiplication binary operator(without using division or other)?

Comment: Note that $1 \notin E$ alone does not imply that $E$ doesn't have an identity (consider $\{0\}$...).

Comment: @fkraiem Doesn't identity refer to: $I*A=A=A*I$, so $A \ne 0$, could only refer to identity $I=1$ for multiplication?

Comment: @fkraiem was that just a comment about the general case and not mine?

Comment: $1$ being the identity for multiplication in $\mathbf{Z}$ only means that $1\cdot a = a\cdot 1 = a$ *for all $a$ in $\mathbf{Z}$*. Given a proper, non-trivial, subset $E$ of $\mathbf{Z}$, it is not immediately clear why there can't be an element $e \in E$ such that $e\cdot a = a\cdot e = a$ *for all $a$ in $E$*. And it is certainly not the case in arbitrary rings, in order to show that it is true in $\mathbf{Z}$ you need to use additional properties of $\mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: So by just saying that $1\notin E$, you have not proved anything, there are tons of counterexamples, $\{0\}$ being the simplest one : $1$ is certainly not in it, and it has an identity (which is $0$).

Comment: @fkraiem Okay I understand now. Yeah that makes sense, I only said that 'obvious' thing based on this situation, but what you say is surely true. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Towards contradiction, let $e$ be the identity of this semigroup.  Then show that $e \ne 0$.  Finally, factor $e = e^2$ as $e(e - 1) = 0$ to derive a contradiction.

Comment: Can you please further that hint. I did easily show that $e\ne0$, but I am not sure how to prove the second equality.

Comment: @DisplayName I thought of a cleaner way to do it.  Does my updated answer help?  You will have to use facts about the integers to prove this.

Comment: Is it because $e=2k, k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $e^2 = 2l,l\in\mathbb{Z}$, so $e=e^2$ but $e^2 \gt e$?

Comment: @DisplayName That works, but the easier way is to use that if the product of two integers is $0$, one of those integers must be $0$.

Comment: I see what you have done now, very clever! Thank you for that!

To finish your statement: Either $e$ is odd($e-1=0$), or $e=0$, contradiction, as $e$ is even, and $e\ne0$